# Limit to Infinity

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error

So I tried to get the limits to infinity of an expression which has a function argument through this code and I got this. Help.

```
     import numpy as np
     import sympy as sp
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     from scipy import integrate

     T=2
     t=sp.symbols('t')
     x=sp.Piecewise((1,t%T<=T/2),(0,t%T>T/2))
     n=sp.symbols('n')

    xnum=sp.lambdify(t,x)

    def realintegrand(t,f):
         w0=2*np.pi/T
         trig=np.cos(n*w0*t)
         return f(t)*trig/T

    def imagintegrand(t,f):
        w0=2*np.pi/T
        trig=np.sin(n*w0*t)
        return f(t)*trig/T

    def limitfunc(f):
        realans, errreal = integrate.quad(realintegrand, 0, T,args=(f,))
        imagans, errimag = integrate.quad(imagintegrand, 0, T,args=(f,))
    
    return sp.limit(realans-1.0j*imagans,n,float('inf'),'+')

    k=limitfunc(xnum)
```

TypeError:
loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable cos method

Comment: You should add a tag of the programming language you are using to your post .

Comment: EDIT: I also tried to change all the np. instances in the function definitions to sp. for cleaner run and I got error: Cannot convert expression to float